# Im try to isolate the white space in ruby sentences

Tags: arrays, ruby, include

I am attempting to place all the characters of a string into its own index in an array and also am trying to replace `" "` (spaces) with 0's. The error I'm getting is that is says

?wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

but I'm not sure how to make `include(' ')` work.

Here is my code:

```
def findMe(words)
  x = 0
  convert = []

  while x < words.length
    if words[x].is_a? String && words[x].include? != " "
      convert << words[x]
    else
      convert << 0
    end
    x = x + 1
  end

  p convert

end

findMe('Words and stuff.')
```

Desired Output: `["W", "o", "r", "d", "s", 0, "a", "n", "d", 0, "s", "t", "u", "f", "f", "."]`

Comment: An example with desired output please.

Comment: ["W", "o", "r", "d", "s", "0", "a", "n", "d", "0", "s", "t", "u", "f", "f", "."] or ["W", "o", "r", "d", "s", 0, "a", "n", "d", 0, "s", "t", "u", "f", "f", "."]

Comment: Thanks. It would be better if you edit your question with the example (then delete your comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the "wrong number of arguments" error here:

```
words[x].include? != " "
```

You can quickly fix this by replacinng it with:

```
!words[x] == " "
```

A better way to do the whole thing would be:

```
words.gsub(" ", "0").chars
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-chars).

```
'Words and stuff.'.chars.map { |c| c ==  " " ? "0" : c }
 #=> ["W", "o", "r", "d", "s", "0", "a", "n", "d", "0", "s", "t", "u", "f", "f", "."]
```